# Jenkins build warnings "source file does not exist" with OctoPack and ReadyRoll

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, octopack, readyroll

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins build project with ReadyRoll.  Mostly it is working but I'm getting warnings that concern me:

```
  MSBUILD : OctoPack warning OCTNOENT: The source file 'c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\bin\Release\' does not exist, so it will not be included in the package [c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\CoreServices.sqlproj]
  MSBUILD : OctoPack warning OCTNOENT: The source file 'c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\obj\Release\CoreServices_Package.sql' does not exist, so it will not be included in the package [c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\CoreServices.sqlproj]
```

I have searched for information on this error and have found nothing helpful.  When I check the build server after the build is completed, the folder and file it says do not exist do, indeed, exist.  That implies to me there is some sort of order of operation error going on here but I don't know where or how that would be occurring.

Here is the section of the log where the warnings are generated:

```
OctoPack:
  Using package version: 8.6.26
  OctoPack: OctoPack version: 3.6.1.0
  OctoPack: Written files: 10
  OctoPack: Copy file: c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\obj\Release\CoreServices.nuspec
  OctoPack: Packaging a console or Window Service application (no Web.config detected)
  OctoPack: Add binary files
  OctoPack: Added file: CoreServices_Package.sql
  OctoPack: Added file: CoreServices_DeployPackage.ps1
  OctoPack: Added file: CoreServices_Snapshot.nupkg.bin
MSBUILD : OctoPack warning OCTNOENT: The source file 'c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\bin\Release\' does not exist, so it will not be included in the package [c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\CoreServices.sqlproj]
  OctoPack: Added file: Deploy.ps1
  OctoPack: Added file: DeployFailed.ps1
MSBUILD : OctoPack warning OCTNOENT: The source file 'c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\obj\Release\CoreServices_Package.sql' does not exist, so it will not be included in the package [c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\CoreServices.sqlproj]
  OctoPack: Added file: CoreServices.dll
  OctoPack: Added file: CoreServices.pdb
  OctoPack: NuGet Version: 3.5.0.38733 (Custom build for OctoPack. See http://g.octopushq.com/VersioningInOctopusDeploy)
  OctoPack: Attempting to build package from 'CoreServices.nuspec'.
  OctoPack: Successfully created package 'c:\scm01-jenkins\workspace\DatabaseDeploys\DatabaseDeploys\CoreServices\obj\octopacked\IC_CoreServices.Database.8.6.26.nupkg'.
```

And here are the MSBuild parameters:

/t:Clean,Build /p:Version=8.6.26.0;Configuration=Release /p:GenerateSqlPackage=True /p:ShadowServer=[shadowdatabasename] /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=8.6.26 /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://[OctopusDeployServer]/nuget/packages /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=[key]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue with ReadyRoll's integration with OctoPack, however the warnings are extraneous and can be safely ignored.

To suppress the warnings, add the following to your MSBuild parameters:

```
/nowarn:OCTNOENT
```

<s>I'll update this answer once the issue is resolved (1003).</s>

A fix for this was released as part of [ReadyRoll 1.16.18100](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/ReadyRoll+1.16+release+notes#ReadyRoll1.16releasenotes-1.16.18100-April10th,2018); the OctoPack warnings should no longer be displayed during build.